# Custom Jackson Deserializer to handle a property of any bean

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class called `Channel` which will have `roles` property as follows

```
public class Channel{
   private int id;
   private String roles;
}
```

And my JSON from client would be

```
{
 "id":"12345787654323468",
 "roles":[
          {"name":"admin","permissions":["can publish","can reject"]},
          {"name":"moderator","permissions":["can publish","can reject"]}
         ]
}
```

But when I convert this JSON to Channel object I am getting following exception

```
com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@6d25f91; line: 1, column: 253] (through reference chain: com.pokuri.entity.Channel["roles"])
```

Now I want to deserialize this as a string into property `roles` of `Channel` class. Also can I write single custom deserializer to handle property of JSON array in any bean.

Comment: I'm curious why you want it to be a String. `Set<Role>` seems more appropriate. What do you expect the final String `roles` to be?

Comment: I am using Cassandra and want to store roles as string in a column...So no need of any new bean and new column family

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom Deserializer can do the trick here. :

```
class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        JsonNode node = jsonParser.readValueAsTree();       
        return node.toString();
    }

}
```

now to use this in your bean, you have to include it on `roles` field :

```
class Channel {
    private long id;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    private String roles;



    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(String roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

}
```

**Note :** I have taken value of `id` as `long` as it was showing error for `int`, as value is too large in `id` attribute.

Now ObjectMapper can easily deserialize your JSON to Channel class :

```
String json = "{\"id\":\"12345787654323468\",\"roles\":[{\"name\":\"admin\",\"permissions\":[\"can publish\",\"can reject\"]},{\"name\":\"moderator\",\"permissions\":[\"can publish\",\"can reject\"]}]}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Channel channel = mapper.readValue(json, Channel.class);

System.out.println("Roles :"+channel.getRoles());
```